# table view creating multiple accessoryType on scrolling on cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi i am using table view to select deselect the  cell and get the desired result. but when i check any cell and scroll down then check shows on other cells too

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        errorText!.removeFromSuperview()

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
         let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        let person = numberArray[indexPath.row]

        if cell.accessoryType == .None {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            selectedPeople.addObject(person)
        }else if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
            selectedPeople.removeObject(person)
        }

        print("\(selectedPeople)")
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCellss", forIndexPath: indexPath)


        for object in cell.contentView.subviews
        {
            object.removeFromSuperview();
        }


        let text1:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(20, 10, 350, 30))
        text1.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(23)
        text1.text = nameArray[indexPath.row] as? String
        cell.contentView.addSubview(text1)

        let text2:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(20, text1.frame.origin.y+text1.frame.size.height , 350, 30 ))
        text2.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        text2.text = numberArray[indexPath.row] as? String
        text2.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        cell.contentView.addSubview(text2)


        let text3:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, text2.frame.origin.y+text2.frame.size.height+6 , 350, 1 ))
        text3.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        text3.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        cell.contentView.addSubview(text3)



        return cell
   }
```

Comment: you have to maintain selection because of resusability of cells

Comment: how should i do that....means i have to check which cells are already check in cell for row at index path.   ?

Comment: pls first implement given below answer...!! its working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        errorText!.removeFromSuperview()

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
         let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        let person = numberArray[indexPath.row]

        if cell.accessoryType == .None {
            selectedPeople.addObject(person)
        }else if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            selectedPeople.removeObject(person)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        print("\(selectedPeople)")
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCellss", forIndexPath: indexPath)


        for object in cell.contentView.subviews
        {
            object.removeFromSuperview();
        }


        let text1:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(20, 10, 350, 30))
        text1.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(23)
        text1.text = nameArray[indexPath.row] as? String
        cell.contentView.addSubview(text1)

        let text2:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(20, text1.frame.origin.y+text1.frame.size.height , 350, 30 ))
        text2.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        text2.text = numberArray[indexPath.row] as? String
        text2.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        cell.contentView.addSubview(text2)


        let text3:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, text2.frame.origin.y+text2.frame.size.height+6 , 350, 1 ))
        text3.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        text3.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        cell.contentView.addSubview(text3)

        if (selectedPeople.contains(numberArray[indexPath.row])){
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = .None
         }

        return cell
   }
```

Comment: kindly answer this question :-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693198/trim-video-without-displaying-uivideoeditorcontroller-swift